# What would you call x0th anniversary?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th etc. anniversary?

It is a special anniversary because it ends with 0. Is there a name for it in English?

suggestions: *round anniversary*, *a milestone anniversary*

Comment: it's a good question, what about a "gem" anniversary?

Comment: [**decennial**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decennial) Adj: *occurring every ten years,* **Noun: *a decennial anniversary.***

Comment: They're often referred to as 'significant' anniversaries (though they're only significant, like a century at cricket, because people consider them so. If we used a different number base ...). However, this term also includes the 25th anniversary.

Comment: @FF Like the first, 11th, 21st ...?

Comment: I have found this link on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_anniversary There they name it after metals, but it is a bit unrelated, though. Another link http://mistupid.com/months/annivnames.htm for anniversary names.

Comment: I don't believe there is a common term.  Most people would say something like "round anniversary" or a (slightly strained) phrase such as "a multiple of ten anniversary".

Comment: ‘Round’ as @HotLicks suggested, was the phrasing that immediately popped into my head, though I can’t tell whether that’s because it’s actually used or from second-language interference. Google would indicate it’s probably the latter, since most hits for ‘round birthday’ and ‘round anniversary’ are suggestions for translations from German or Scandinavian languages.

Answer (score 2):

As Fumblefingers said in the comments:

> **[decennial](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decennial)** Adj: occurring every ten years, Noun: a decennial anniversary.

Linked is the dictionary.com page for decennial, which lists as an example the following:

> noun
>   3.
>   a decennial anniversary.

Answer (score 0):

For anniversaries that are considered significant because of the "roundness" of the number of years being commemorated, I believe the most common formal term is one of your suggestions, **milestone anniversary**. Somewhat more common is the less-formal **big anniversary**<sup>1</sup>. The two are also used in conjunction, as *big, milestone anniversary*. However, these don't exclusively refer to anniversaries that come in multiples of ten (the other suggestion of *decennial* is correct for that).

The definition of "big" or "milestone" understandably varies by source and also by type of anniversary, but these typically are the first, and then multiples of 5, 10, 25, 50, 100 etc. with the smaller divisions becoming less significant as the number gets higher<sup>2</sup>. Some examples of usage:

> Celebrating Those **BIG Anniversaries** In Style
>   Although Anniversaries
>   come along every year, the majority of them aren’t thought of as that
>   special as they are a random 3, 11, 17 years etc (although let’s face
>   it, every year is an achievement!) However, what about those **big,
>   milestone Anniversaries**, surely they deserve some extra recognition?
>   This is what we try to achieve as part of BasketsGalore’s Anniversary
>   Gift Baskets. As well as gift baskets to celebrate general
>   anniversaries we also theme ones for Silver, Pearl, Ruby Golden &
>   Diamond Anniversaries i.e 25, 30, 40, 50 and 60 year anniversaries –
>   wow! ([Baskets Galore blog](https://basketsgalore.co.uk/blog/2015/05/celebrating-those-big-anniversaries-in-style/))
>
> I know compared to some couples, five years is not huge, but for us, this is our first **big “milestone” anniversary**. ([Sarah Marier, *Huffington Post* column](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/a-letter-to-myself-on-my-wedding-day_us_57aa34a8e4b024b403af3599?section=us_weddings))
>
> **Milestone Anniversary** ([Papyrus card category](https://www.papyrusonline.com/greeting-cards/anniversary-cards/milestone-anniversary-cards); includes 25th and
>   50th)
>
> **Milestone Anniversary** (*Chattanooga Times Free Press* feature; this
>   date lists 60th, 65th, 70th, and 75th wedding anniversaries)
>
> 16 Classic Movies With **Big Anniversaries** In 2016 ([Moviepilot](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3796791);
>   lists 10th, 15th, 20th, and 30th anniversaries)
>
> 2016 to Celebrate Two **Big Anniversaries**
>   The
>   New Year 2016 will mark two significant anniversaries for the U.S.
>   numismatic community. The first, and probably most important, is the
>   100th birthday of three of America’s most beloved coinage designs of
>   the 20th century. . . . The New Year’s second anniversary is a bit
>   closer to home. In 2016, PCGS will celebrate its 30th anniversary.
>   ([Mike Sherman, Professional Coin Grading Service News](http://www.pcgs.com/news/2016-to-celebrate-two-big-anniversaries/))

<sup>1</sup> The term *major anniversaries* is actually more common than all of these, but this often refers to the significance of the event being commemorated, rather than the anniversary number. See [Google Ngram here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+anniversary%2Cbig+anniversaries%2Cmilestone+anniversary%2Cmilestone+anniversaries%2Cmajor+anniversary%2Cmajor+anniversaries&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbig%20anniversary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbig%20anniversaries%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmilestone%20anniversary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmilestone%20anniversaries%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmajor%20anniversary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmajor%20anniversaries%3B%2Cc0), with the [usual caveats](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/pitfalls-of-studying-language-with-google-ngram/).

<sup>2</sup> That is, the fifth anniversary is almost certainly considered a big milestone, the fifteenth perhaps less-so; by the time you get to 235 probably no one pays attention—I don't remember any big celebration in the US four years ago, for example. One caveat for this is that anniversaries near or past the expected lifetime of the person or thing being commemorated may become more significant in small denominations (i.e. a 102nd birthday and a 2nd birthday are both often treated as significant, even though a 52nd birthday passes unremarked.)